# Question about positive variations of function

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Given a function $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{C}$, Folland in his book "Real Analysis" defines the total variation of $f$ at $x \in \mathbb{R}$ as
$$
T_f(x) = \sup \left\{\sum_{1}^n |f(x_j)-f(x_{j-1})|: -\infty < x_0 <x_1 < \dots x_n = x , n \in \mathbb{N} \right \}
$$
and the space $BV(R)$ as the set of those functions with finite $T_f(x)$ for $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Then, for $f \in BV(R)$, he defines the positive variation of $f$ denoted by  $v(f)^+$
$$
v(f)^+ := \frac{1}{2} (T_f+f)(x) = \sup \left\{\sum_{1}^n [f(x_j)-f(x_{j-1})]^+: -\infty < x_0 <x_1 < \dots x_n = x , n \in \mathbb{N} \right \} + f(-\infty)$$

but I do not understand where the term $f(-\infty)$ comes from.

What I was able to get is
$$ 
v(f)^+  =  \sup \left\{\sum_{1}^n [f(x_j)-f(x_{j-1})]^+ + \frac{1}{2}f(x_0): -\infty < x_0 <x_1 < \dots x_n = x , n \in \mathbb{N} \right \}
$$

What am I missing?

Comment: I think there is an error in the book. Instead of $f(-\infty)$ we should have $\frac 1 2 f(-\infty)$

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy How do you get the term $f(-\infty)$ anyways?

Comment: In the expression you have obtained take sup over all $x_0 <x_1$ and the take sup over the remaining $x_i$'s.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Could you show me the details please? I still didn't understand :(

Answer (score 2):

I agree that the formula needs the term $1/2$ as suggested by Kavi Rama Murthy.

First of all, recall that given $x \in \mathbb{R}$, $2x^+=|x|+x$. Take $x \in \mathbb{R}$, $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $\left\{ x_j: j=0,...,n \right\}$ such that $-\infty<x_0<...<x_n=x$. Take a strictly decreasing sequence $\left(y_k\right)_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ such that $\lim_{k \to \infty} y_k = -\infty$ and $y_1<x_0$. Given $k \in \mathbb{N}$, note that
\begin{align*}
\sum_{j=1}^n \left[ f(x_j)-f(x_{j-1}) \right]^+
&\leq
\left[ f(x_0)-f(y_k) \right]^++\sum_{j=1}^n \left[ f(x_j)-f(x_{j-1}) \right]^+
\\
&\leq
\frac{1}{2}\left\{ \left| f(x_0)-f(y_k) \right|+\left[ f(x_0)-f(y_k) \right]+\left[ f(x)-f(x_0)\right]+\sum_{j=1}^n \left| f(x_j)-f(x_{j-1}) \right|\right\}
\\
&\leq
\frac{1}{2}\left\{ \left| f(x_0)-f(y_k) \right|+\left[ f(x)-f(y_k) \right]+\sum_{j=1}^n \left| f(x_j)-f(x_{j-1}) \right|\right\}
\\
&\leq
\frac{1}{2}\left[ T_f(x)+f(x)-f(y_k)\right]
\end{align*}

Passing to the limit, we obtain
$$
\sum_{j=1}^n \left[ f(x_j)-f(x_{j-1}) \right]^+
\leq
\frac{1}{2}\left[ T_f(x)+f(x)-f(-\infty)\right]
$$

Therefore, we obtain the inequality $\leq$ where the left-hand side is obtained as the supremum of those sums over the considered partitions.

We are left with the question of whether the right-hand side is reached by such supremum.

It indeed is: take a sequence of partitions $\left( P_k \right)_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ where given $k \in \mathbb{N}$, $n_k \in \mathbb{N}$ and $P_k=\left\{ x^k_i : i=0,...,n_k\right\}$ with $x^k_i < x^k_{i+1}$ for any $i=0,...,n_k$ such that $\lim_{k \to \infty}\sum_{i=0}^{n_k} \left[ f(x_i)-f(x_{i-1}) \right]^+$ is the supremum of those sums over the set of finite partitions.

Let $\left( y_k \right)_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence such that $\lim_{k \to \infty} y_k=-\infty$ and given $k \in \mathbb{N}$, $y_k<x^k_0$. Consider the new sequence of partitions $\left( P_k \cup \{ y_k \} \right)_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$. Each element of such sequence gives us an even greater sum, so it still converges to the supremum, and we got the new term we needed to obtain the $f(-\infty)$.

Comment: The last part is not quite clear i.e. how to get the reverse inequality is still unclear to me.

Comment: Your argument on the reverse inequality does not work. Instead we can argue along the following lines $:$ Let $\alpha$ denote that supremum. Let $x\in \mathbb R$ and $\varepsilon \gt 0$ be given. Then there exists a partition $-\infty\lt x_0\lt x_1\lt\cdots\lt x_n=x$ such that $$\sum\limits_{j = 1}^{n}|f(x_j) - f(x_{j-1})| \geq T_f(x) - \varepsilon.$$ Consider a sequence $(y_k)$ of real numbers with $y_k \lt x_0$ for all $k$ such that $y_k \to -\infty$ as $k \to \infty.$ Then for all $k$ we have $$\sum\limits_{j = 1}^{n} |f(x_j) - f(x_{j-1})|+|f(x_0)-f(y_k)| \geq T_f(x) - \varepsilon.$$ contd

Comment: This implies that for all $k,$ $$2 \left [\sum\limits_{j = 1}^{n} [f(x_j) - f(x_{j-1})]^+ +[f(x_0)-f(y_k)]^+ \right ] - [(f(x) - f(x_0)) + (f(x_0) - f(y_k))] \geq T_f(x) - \varepsilon.$$ This implies that $$2 \left [\sum\limits_{j = 1}^{n} [f(x_j) - f(x_{j-1})]^+ +[f(x)-f(y_k)]^+ \right ] - [f(x) - f(y_k)] \geq T_f(x) - \varepsilon.$$ Now we have $$\alpha \geq \sum\limits_{j = 1}^{n} [f(x_j) - f(x_{j-1})]^+ +[f(x_0)-f(y_k)]^+.$$ So it follows that for all $k,$ $$2 \alpha - f(x) + f(y_k) \geq T_f(x) - \varepsilon.$$ contd

Comment: Letting $k \to \infty$ we have $$2 \alpha + f (-\infty) \geq T_f (x) + f(x) - \varepsilon.$$ Since the above inequality holds for any $\varepsilon \gt 0$ letting $\varepsilon \to 0$ we have $$2 \alpha + f (-\infty) \geq T_f (x) + f(x),$$ which is exactly what we wanted to show.

Comment: @AkiroKurosawa In the last paragraph, I did not intend to prove that $\geq$ also holds. What I did was to construct an explicit sequence of partitions, $(P_k \cup \{y_k\})_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$, such that if we consider the limit $k \to \infty$, the expression on the left-hand side tends to the quantity on the right-hand side. I did not check your argument, but different approaches might also work.