# Understanding Jordan decomposition of a function of bounded variation

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I am reading the book Real Analysis by Folland, and I found that someone else asked the same question that I currently have in 
[Question about positive variations of function](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2741786/585053)

For a function $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{C}$ of bounded variation, let me first write 
$$
v(f) = \sup \left\{\sum_{1}^n [f(x_j)-f(x_{j-1})]^+: -\infty < x_0 <x_1 < \dots x_n = x , n \in \mathbb{N} \right \} + \frac{1}{2}f(-\infty)$$
and
$$
u(f)  =  \sup \left\{\sum_{1}^n [f(x_j)-f(x_{j-1})]^+ + \frac{1}{2}f(x_0): -\infty < x_0 <x_1 < \dots x_n = x , n \in \mathbb{N} \right \}
$$

In order to show $v(f) = u(f)$, I want to show that any upper bound of the set for $v$ is an upper bound of the set for $u$, and vice versa. But without knowing how $f$ behaves as $x \to -\infty$, how is this possible?

Comment: Read the lemma 3.26 in which author shows $u_f±f$ are increasing and notice that $f$ is nothing but average of $u_f+f,f-u_f$ and $lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} g(x)\in [-\infty,\infty]$ for any increasing function g.

Comment: @Matematleta The discussion following thm 3.27 claims $u(f) = v(f)$ for which I am asking a formal proof, but $v(f) = \frac{1}{2}(T_f+f)$ by definition. Are we on the same page?

Comment: Yes, you are right. I am looking for a proof of the same thing as you. I will delete my original comment.

Comment: @Matematleta I mean $u(f) = \frac{1}{2}(T_f + f)$ by definition since the definition of $T_f$ does involve $f(x_0)$ , instead of $f(-\infty)$?

Comment: I am working on a proof from scratch.

Comment: @Matematleta Please let me know if you manage to provide a formal proof!

Comment: I made an attempt. Perhaps it would have been better as a comment, but it's too long. So I posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\sum_{1}^n [f(x_j)-f(x_{j-1})]^+ + \frac{1}{2}f(x_0)\le u(f)$ for any partition $P$.

For $\epsilon>0$, there is an $x_0$ such that $f(-\infty)-\epsilon<f(x_0)<f(-\infty)+\epsilon$. Without loss of generality, we may assume that $P$ contains $x_0$. Then,

$\sum_{1}^n [f(x_j)-f(x_{j-1})]^+ + \frac{1}{2}f(-\infty)\le \sum_{1}^n [f(x_j)-f(x_{j-1})]^+ + \frac{1}{2}f(x_0)+\frac{1}{2}\epsilon\le u(f)+\frac{1}{2}\epsilon.$

This is true for all partitions $P$ so in fact, $v(f)\le u(f).$

Now fix a partition $P.$ Then, $\sum_{1}^n [f(x_j)-f(x_{j-1})]^+ + \frac{1}{2}f(-\infty)\le v(f)$

And for $\epsilon>0$, there is an $x_0$ such that $f(-\infty)-\epsilon<f(x_0)<f(-\infty)+\epsilon$. Without loss of generality, we may assume $P$ contains $x_0$. Then,

$\sum_{1}^n [f(x_j)-f(x_{j-1})]^++\frac{1}{2}f(x_0)\le \sum_{1}^n [f(x_j)-f(x_{j-1})]^+ + \frac{1}{2}f(-\infty)+\frac{1}{2}\epsilon\le v(f)+\frac{1}{2}\epsilon,$ which, on suping over all partitions $P$, implies that $u(f)\le v(f).$

Comment: When you pass to the limit, there is $f(x_0)$ in the summation that should also go to $f(-\infty)$ shouldn't it? That was something I could not figure out

Comment: For the finite partition $P$ we fix all the points in $P$ except $x_0$. In other words, for each value of $x_0$ we get a finite partition $P_{x_0}$.

Comment: When you take the limit $x_0 \to -\infty$, you get $\frac{1}{2} f(x_0) \to \frac{1}{2} f(-\infty)$. But note that the "last" term in your sum $\Sigma$ is $f(x_1)-f(x_0)$ so it should go to $f(x_1)-f(-\infty)$ shouldn't it?

Comment: Yes, indeed. Thanks! I need to fix this---

Comment: I think it is ok now.